# How do I use a component from a different module to be the main component in routing declarations

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing

**Angular newbie here, your patience is highly appreciated.**

**What am I trying to achieve?**

- I'm trying to use the component in my **auth module(i.e login
  component)** as the base component for the route **myapp.com/login**
- Assuming that when embedding  **in **app.component.html** works fine, the same should be true when I put that in app-**routing.module.ts**

**code for app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '/login', component: LoginComponent}, //Cannot find name 'LoginComponent'.ts(2304)
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**My component structure**

- I have an auth module which has a login and register components
- And the basic ng-cli generated app structure.

code for authmodule
**auth.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [RegisterComponent, LoginComponent],
  exports:[RegisterComponent,LoginComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

**code for app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import {AppCommonsModule} from './app-commons/app-commons.module';
import {AuthModule} from './auth/auth.module'

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component'
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AppCommonsModule,
    AuthModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: You need to import ```LoginComponent``` at top of  ```app-routing.module.ts``` as like  ```HomeComponent``` ..

Comment: Sure, but Whats the point in importing this modlue in app.module.ts ?

Comment: The `app-routing.module.ts` is the "controller" for the routing. The other modules are the "controller" for the meeting place for everything to be able to see each other. You see in `app-routing.module.ts`, you are not putting `LoginComponent` in a `declarations: []`. In order to use a component, it has to be in a `declarations: []`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly refer components declared as part of other modules in AppRoutingModule. You have to delegate the routing of LoginComponent to AuthModule by creating an AuthRoutingModule. Then in AppRoutingModule, create a route for `login` and pass the control to AuthRoutingModule.

Follow the below steps to create a route for LoginComponent.

1. Create a new file called `AuthRoutingModule` and include routes for the components in AuthModule in this file.

**auth-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';

const authRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', // considering LoginComponent as the root path for AuthModule. This will be referred as 'login' from AppRoutingModule
    pathMatch: 'full', // this is important to correctly match the empty path
    component: LoginComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(authRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AuthRoutingModule {}
```

Note that `forChild()` method used here. `RouterModule.forRoot()` should be used only once and it should preferrable be there in AppRoutingModule. `RouterModule.forChild()` is used for creating routes for other child modules (and hence the forChild name).

2. Import AuthRoutingModule in AuthModule file.
3. Modify your AppRoutingModule file as below.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

const authRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full', // this is important to correctly match the empty path
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule)
    // now this will refer the root path of AuthRoutingModule
  },
  // Redirect all invalid URLs to HomeComponent
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(authRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

As shown in the above code snippet, if you want to load a component from a child module for a particular route, AppRoutingModule should redirect the control to the child module using the `loadChildren` property.

4. You would have already imported both AppRoutingModule and AuthModule in your AppModule file. Just make sure that you are loading the AppRoutingModule first and then other child modules with routing (i.e., AuthModule in your case).
5. If you want lazy loading, remove all child modules(with routes) from `AppModule` imports. More on lazy loading [here](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules).

Refer [Angular official docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading-route-configuration) for more information on child modules routing.

I have also created a sample [stackblitz app for demo purposes](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g2ewkg).

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to `LoginComponent` in routing file but not importing it.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '/login', component: LoginComponent}, //Cannot find name 'LoginComponent'.ts(2304)
];
```

Add import statement and I believe it should fix typescript error.

```
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
```

Comment: Good catch. But this might not work for all cases, especially if OP is using (or decides to use) lazy loading.

Comment: @Shravan yes, but from what is posted it does not look like lazy loading is used.